# How to get a query error from prepare() in PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM c6ode");
```

How can I check the intentional mysql error for the query in above case?

Answer (score 79):

You need to set the error mode attribute `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

And since you expect the exception to be thrown by the `prepare()` method, you should disable the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` feature. Otherwise the MySQL server doesn't "see" the statement until it's executed.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO DoesNotExist (x) VALUES (?)');
```

prints (or logs, depends on the PHP settings)

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'test.doesnotexist' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Why use Try/Catch when PDO traps the error anyway?

Answer (score 56):

I'm using this without any additional settings:

```
if (!$st->execute()) {
    print_r($st->errorInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 25):

I'm guessing that your complaint is that the exception is not firing. PDO is most likely configured to not throw exceptions. Enable them with this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Nope still not working, i know my query is wrong, but i want to display that error.

Comment: You may find that there is an error with the call to `new PDO(...` itself. Try increasing the level of error_reporting by setting for example `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Answer (score 14):

a quick way to see your errors whilst testing:

```
$error= $st->errorInfo();
echo $error[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

/* Provoke an error -- the BONES table does not exist */

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT skull FROM bones');
$sth->execute();

echo "\nPDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";
$arr = $sth->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => -204
    [2] => [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUX] SQL0204N  "DANIELS.BONES" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
)
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function errorInfo()