# PDO Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

#### EDIT: Fixed, something went wrong with some variables, works fine now!

Working code:

```
if($q = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `ba_keys` SET `times_used` = :used WHERE `betacode` = :beta"))
    {
        $q->bindValue(':used', 90);
        $q->bindValue(':beta', $betacode);
        if($q->execute())
        {
            return 'Execution done.';
        } else {
            return 'Execution failed.';
        }
    } else {
        return 'Query preparing failed.';
    }
```

Comment: Try getting the error info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php

Answer (score 1):

You do not need single quotes in the Prepared Statement. PDO will handle that for you. Your code should be:

```
$q = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `ba_keys` SET `times_used` = :used WHERE `betacode` = :beta");
$q->bindValue(':used', 90);
$q->bindValue(':beta', $betacode);
$q->execute();
```

You might also wish to consider returning the result of `$q->execute()` from your function, for completeness.