# SQL Injection: Which statement can prevent better SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO statement as below

```
select * from `admine_user` where `user_id` = ? and passw = ?
$resultfm1 = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute
(array($escapedid,$hashedpass))->fetchAll();
```

I am thinking to use

```
select * from `admine_user` where `user_id` = :user and passw = :pwd
$resultfm1 = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute
(array(":user"=>$escapedid,":pwd"=>$hashedpass))->fetchAll();
```

Out of above statements which is better to use which can prevent SQL injection effectively as now i can not use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Thanks @sectus.. and someone downvoted, can i know reason and thanks for person who upvoted.. I think we are here to learn

Comment: You should make sure your prepares aren't emulated (`$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`) - [Read More.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php/8776392#8776392). But yes both queries do the same thing.

Comment: Yes they both prepare if your db instanve is pdo. They are actualle the same query. One just uses nameholders.

Comment: Neither is better than the other, and they will both effectively prevent SQL injection. Use the one you like better.

Comment: It is set to `TRUE` .. if it is TRUE then is SQL injection Possible?

Comment: Where did these doubts come from?

Comment: @CodeFreak There is a still a possibility -> [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/a/134138/2518525) Related to my comment before.

Comment: @sectus .. i was studying it somewhere but was not satisfied.. so thought to ask experts here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL only supports positional parameters (the `?` placeholders), so PDO internally converts named parameters into positional parameters during the prepare step.

So in fact both styles ultimately do the same thing with respect to MySQL.

Also, "emulated prepares" doesn't actually do anything in the prepare step, it just saves the query string. When you execute, you supply values and they are interpolated into the query and then submitted to MySQL. If you don't trust this process, then disable emulated prepares.

This is not to say that PDO does anything unsafe, although early versions of PDO had some bugs.

Just make sure you're using a current version of PDO (basically anything in PHP 5.3 or newer), and then both styles are as safe as one can be.

Notwithstanding any regression bugs that may occur after I write this...

Comment: +1 I didn't know that PDO converts named parameters to positional. Does this mean that there is a performance benefit to using positional parameters over named?

Comment: yeah.. @bill karwin .. i am using PHP 5.3 only

Comment: @MarkM, don't worry about any performance difference between positional and named parameters. It's just a few lines of C code, so the difference will barely be measurable. You can benchmark it if you want, but I predict your time will be better spent optimizing your PHP code instead, or analyzing SQL queries to create the right indexes.