# PHP PDO Display Formatted Error To User

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two unique keys 'phone' and 'email'. When a duplicate key is getting inserted I'm getting the error posted below:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4294967295-xyz@gmail.com' for key 'phone'
```

What I'm trying to do is display the thrown error to the user like posted below:

```
1. Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'phone'
2. Duplicate entry 'xyz@gmail.com' for key 'email'
```

How can I do that?

Here's what I have done to get the error displayed on front-end:

```
catch( PDOException $Exception ){
    if ($Exception->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $Exception->getMessage();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and your attempts

Comment: Try this: `echo $stmt->errorInfo()[2];` Is this what you want?

Comment: Instead of parsing PDO exceptions, I would probably use different queries (and ajax as soon as a field looses focus...) to validate the different input fields. That would also give you a lot more flexibility where the error messages are concerned.

Comment: You may like to take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php

Comment: @popla BTW: I think your only able to get 1 error message, because the second one will never be found, because it stops when it finds the first error

Comment: @Rizier123: Yes, you're right. Seems Like jeroen's way is the only way out.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be inserting a value in your auto-increment field. The system will create it for you.

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned an auto-increment field. He's just got a composite key in the table set as `UNIQUE` and wants to capture the error when a duplicate value is created thre.

Comment: What does the front end side of this look like?