# Trying to get property of non-object in PHP PDO

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Following function I used in a login page in php. Its showing a error that

> " Trying to get property of non-object in...."

```
function Validate($userName,$encrypted_password,$dbh)
    {
        try{
            echo ("".$userName."");
            echo ("".$encrypted_password."");
            $sql = "SELECT USERCODE,PWD FROM GUSER WHERE USERCODE = :uname AND PWD = :pwd";
            echo $sql->error;
            $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(':uname',$userName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':pwd',$encrypted_password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            echo ("".$rows."");
            if($rows > 0){
                echo "Login Successfull";
                header("location: home.php");
            }
            else{
                $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
                $errflag = true;
            }
            if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            echo "Closed";
            exit();
            }
        }                   
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        //return $getValue;

    }
```

Can anyone help me out.. I am new to php.. Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks to @Saty for fixing up the code. Your SQL Query is wrong.

Comment: Can you explain what wrong in query??@Jimmy

Comment: Whats wrong with my query??

Comment: Yeah. Your query is wrong.

Comment: Those who say his query is wrong - how do you know that? :D You guys even read and understood his question and error he is getting or you just start typing comments?

Comment: whts wrong?? i couldn't find anything. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is not an object:

```
$sql = "SELECT USERCODE,PWD FROM GUSER WHERE USERCODE = :uname AND PWD = :pwd"; // STRING
echo $sql->error; // but you try to access it like it's an object
```

`$sql` is `string` so it doesn't have properties like `error` and you can't access it like `$sql->error`, because it's a primitive value type.

You have to delete this line:

```
echo $sql->error;
```

To handle SQL errors in PDO you have to use try-catch construct in PHP. [See this answer for more information about handling errors in PDO.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8776392/2166409)

Comment: Its only printing "Closed" that specified in last if statement. Any error with my query?

Comment: You have to delete line: `echo $sql->error;`. Do this and error is fixed.

Comment: i deleted. then i ran my code in browser. its printing "sysman 1594 Closed" only.

Comment: So error is gone. You were asking about this error only. How your database structure like? Maybe you should have `USER` table name instead of `GUSER`? How this table look like and what's it name in MYSQL?

Comment: It's is not finding the user because you are printing Closed when the $errflags variable is set to true. So for some reason it is not finding the user -password combination in the DB.

Comment: Table name is GUSER. Its a oracle database

Comment: Are you sure you use correct username and password? I guess you have 0 rows and login fails and that's what you're asking.