# PHP/MySQL to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to change MySQL to PDO:

```
$mapa = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from mapa where id = ".$postac['mapa']." limit 1"));
$mapa_d = mysql_query("select * from mapa_d where mapa = ".$mapa['id']." ");
```

PHP:

```
 $_SESSION['postac'] = $_POST['postac'];
```

try like this so far:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mapa WHERE id=:mapa");  
$stmt->bindValue(':mapa', $postac, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->EXECUTE();  
$postac = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

mysql update:

```
mysql_query("update postac set logged = 1 where id = ".$_SESSION['postac']." limit 1");
```

PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("update postac set logged = 1 where id:postac");  
$stmt->bindValue(':postac', $_SESSION, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->EXECUTE();  
$_SESSION = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Does not work.

Comment: @mishanon don't work

Comment: `$postac['mapa']` is int or string?

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar yes.how i can show error on page?

Comment: i am asking the value you are binding is int or string?

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar  int

Comment: Do you have an error, what's the error ?

Comment: Please, don't ever say "doesn't work". That's the most irritatingly vague you can describe a problem. Do you get an error? Does your computer emit sparks and catch on fire like in Star Trek? Tell us **something**. Also, it's `execute()`. Case can matter, don't yell.

Comment: only show connect message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pre-Answer Note:**

I assume you have already set up a [PDO connection construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection) (`$pdo`) before trying to run your PDO queries.

> ```
> $mapa = mysql_fetch_array(
>           mysql_query("select * from mapa WHERE id = ".$postac['mapa']." limit 1"));
> $mapa_d = mysql_query("select * from mapa_d WHERE mapa = ".$mapa['id']." ");
> ```
>
> PHP:
>
> ```
>  $_SESSION['postac'] = $_POST['postac'];
> ```
>
> try like this so far:
>
> ```
> $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mapa WHERE id=:mapa");  
> $stmt->bindValue(':mapa', $postac, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
> $stmt->EXECUTE();  
> $postac = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> ```

## PART 1:

### Be Consistent

Your original statement uses a value `$postac['mapa']` as an id reference in the `MySQL_` query, but then your PDO statement you are passing *the whole array* as a value into the PDO query.

First, MySQL: `id ==>  $postac['mapa']`

Second, PDO: `id ==> $postac`

So this is causing an immediate issue as you're passing a whole array in to PDO which is somehow expected to extract one value from this array. This array is being classed as a `string` with your `PDO::PARAM_STR` declaration so this is preventing the query from using this value, as it doesn't fit what it's told to expect.

Therefore this returns a NULL query.

So to fix it,

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mapa WHERE id=:mapa");  
 $stmt->bindValue(':mapa', $postac['mapa'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
 $stmt->execute();  
 $postac = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

## Part 2:

### Syntax

> ```
> $stmt = $pdo->prepare("update postac set logged = 1 where id:postac");  
> $stmt->bindValue(':postac', $_SESSION, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
> $stmt->EXECUTE();  
> $_SESSION = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> ```

As above, you're passing the whole `$_SESSION` array as a `PARAM_STR` value, so it's returning VOID /NULL. You also have a syntax fault that you're using `WHERE id:postac`, but you really mean `WHERE id = :postac` be careful of missing out syntax such as `=` !!.

## PART 3:

### Error Checking

It is well worth exploring and learning how to get useful error feedback on PHP PDO, as it will save you posting to StackOverfow X times a day (hopefully!)! 
There is a [good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8776392/3536236) about how to setup PDO to output errors. It is also well worth browsing the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for PDO error checking details.