# PHP display all rows from a table in a table only displays Array ( )

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

    $user = 'mgs_user';
    $password = 'pa55word';
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=portfolio', $user, $password);
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Player_Team");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    print_r($result);
?>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I only get a result of Array ( )

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your query found no records, so it returned an empty result set. Check `$statement->rowCount()`. it'll probably be `0`.

Comment: run this directly `"SELECT * FROM Player_Team"` on your db table and check anything coming or not?

Comment: I ran the "SELECT * FROM Player_Team" and It returned all 8 results.

Comment: <?php

    $user = 'mgs_user';
    $password = 'pa55word';
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=portfolio', $user, $password);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Player_Team");
    if (!$stmt) {
  echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
  print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
 }
 $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    print_r($result);
?>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php

Comment: I made a idiot rookie mistake, must be tired. I never imported the .sql file into myphpadmin. Thanks guys!