# PDO fetchAll always returns an empty array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get an empty array when running:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:127.0.0.1:dbname=mytodo', 'root', 'root');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect.');
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare('select * from todos');

$statement->execute();

var_dump($statement->fetchAll());
```

I've checked the database and running the same query 'select * from todos' returns the results as expected.
I've tried using different databases and tables. I always get an empty array.
Any ideas as to what's going wrong?
I'm running MAMP PRO and get the same issue whatever PHP version I choose.

Any answers or pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: do you need a semi colon instead of a colon after the loop back address?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);` and you have `mysql:127.0.0.1:dbname` being a colon instead of a semi-colon, is that your real code or not? If so, checking for errors on that would have thrown you something about it.

Comment: @johnelemans they most certainly do, unless that was just a bad paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default PDO will die silently on a lot of query errors. Try to check for typo errors also.

[How to view query error in PDO PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php)

// The rest of the statement can also go into the try block. And why not echo the $e error msg if you have one?

Comment: Thanks,
Late night coding typos. Updated code
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mytodo', 'root', 'root');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare('select * from todos');

$statement->execute();

var_dump($statement->fetchAll());

Comment: You can add multiple catch blocks. 1st catch '\Exception' then '\PDOException'.