# PHP PDO insert not returning expect from operation

Tags: php, database, pdo, insert

```
try {
                    print_r($con->_con);
                    $save_transaction1 = $con->_con->prepare("INSERT INTO hpay "
                            . "(amt,entryby,orno,chrgcode) VALUES "
                            . "(:amt,:entryby,:orno,:chrgcode)");
                    $save_transaction1->bindValue(":amt", $tenderedamount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $save_transaction1->bindValue(":entryby", $_SESSION['account_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $save_transaction1->bindValue(":orno", $ornumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $save_transaction1->bindValue(":chrgcode", $chargecode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    if ($save_transaction1->execute()) {
                        echo "asd";
                    } else {
                        print_r($con->_con->errorInfo());
                    }
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e;
                }
```

I have this to insert data in my database. But what I am getting is not what I expect it is not inseting in database, the print_r() i get is

**Updated Error**

> PDO Object ( ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 0 [2] => ((null)[0] at (null):0) [3] => )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php

Comment: what is $dbh and $con?

Comment: @Exprator sorry i didnt change that from the example i found in SO i change it and posted the error

Comment: @Exprator what is the meaning of error? i dont understand the error

Comment: the error means the variable that you are passing in the bindvalue is blank, try to print and check if those have values in it

Comment: @Exprator i get `PDO Object ( ) tenderedamount 95.00id 8ornumber 1chargecode W14-213201Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 0 [2] => ((null)[0] at (null):0) [3] => )` meaning all values have value but still not inserting because the echos of 4 values are `tenderedamount 95.00id 8ornumber 1chargecode W14-213201` it is not null

Comment: try to check the database fields type, keep all varchar with 255 length

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145411/discussion-between-giant-and-exprator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error

`Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 0 [2] => ((null)[0] at (null):0) [3] => )`

Means that there are not null columns and are inserted with null meaning that you cant insert null into not null columns

> Solution:

Change not null columns into null columns