# Getting a "Undefined variable" error on my registration form and I do not know how to fix it

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I am creating a registration form and I am getting a "Undefined variable" error, the full error goes like this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpacademy\cms\admin\signup.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpacademy\cms\admin\signup.php on line 9

Now first of all my database for the register form goes like this:

```
Schema Name:cms

Tables:users,articles

Users table:user_id,user_name,user_password
```

Now for the code I have `index.php`, `connection.php` and `signup.php` Here is the code:

index.php:

```
        <?php

echo "<form action='signup.php' method='POST'>
      <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username'><br>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'><br>
    <button type='submit'>SIGN UP</button>
</form>";
?>
```

signup.php:

```html
<?php

require 'connection.php';

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
    VALUES(:username, :password)");
$result = $statement->execute(array(
    "username" => $username,
    "password" => $password
));
$statement = null;

?>
```

and connection.php:

```html
 <?php

try{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 exit('Database error.');
 
}
 if(empty($pdo)) die("pdo variable is empty!");
?>
```

Now just so you guys know this is `index.php` is a part of a larger code,also because this is a part of a much bigger file when i put the connection.php in a another folder I get an error of the `connection.php` couldn't be found, if you guys have any more questions I'll answer them,thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: You're not showing the correct lines from signup.php so we can't point out the exact issue, but check the dup link.

Comment: Sorry I do not know what  happend i edited the post hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your variables.

In signup.php

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Place this modifications just below the

```
require('connection.php');
```

Also do not store passwords in plain text. It's highly unsafe. 
Use:

```
password_hash
```

And

```
password_verify
```

EDIT
You did not properly bind the placeholders. Also you are accessing the wrong columns. The modified version is below

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password)
VALUES(:username, :password)");
$result = $statement->execute(array(
":username" => $username, //bind placeholders properly 
":password" => $password  // bind placeholders properly 
));

$statement = null;
```

Comment: I edited the code and now i do not get an error but nothing is entered inside my database :<?php





require 'connection.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];


$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
    VALUES(:username, :password)");
$result = $statement->execute(array(
    "username" => $username,
    "password" => $password
));
$statement = null;

?>

Comment: I'm sorry, what did you actually change in the query itself? I seem to be missing it. EDIT- Nevermind, I see the colons now. Keep in mind @Crepi you could just do `VALUES(?, ?)` and then bind with `execute([$username, $password])`. With PDO I believe this is the way the query is sent to the database either way, and it's easier to read for me.

Comment: Just the placeholder in the execute function.

Comment: Sorry I still do not get anything in my db @Akintunde <?php





require 'connection.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES(:username, :password)");
$result = $statement->execute(array(
":username" => $username, //bind placeholders properly 
":password" => $password
));

$statement = null;

?> Maybe there is a problem with my form or connection,I do not know,sorry....

Comment: My bad.  I've fixed it. You were accessing the wrong column names.  Check out the updated query

Comment: Solved the issue,the issue was in the INSER INTO users(user_name, user_password) it my rows were not named username and password,thanks for help tho!

Answer (score 0):

signup.php is doesn't have a value for $username or $password. You need to add `$username = $_POST['username']` and the same thing for the password

Comment: Hi edited my code thanks for help but now I dont get an error but nothing is put into my database:<?php





require 'connection.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];


$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
    VALUES(:username, :password)");
$result = $statement->execute(array(
    "username" => $username,
    "password" => $password
));
$statement = null;

?>

Comment: It looks like your table column names are incorrect. The query is trying to insert into `username`, but your question says the table has `user_name`. You should also turn on the PDO error reporting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php

Comment: Solved the issue,the issue was in the INSER INTO users(user_name, user_password) it my rows were not named username and password,thanks for help tho!