# Statement returns no records despite the parameter values provided in execute

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

When using a vardump on my dropdown list, I am getting a bool(false) error.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT w_Continent.ID, w_Continent.NAME as continent_name, w_Country.Name, w_Country.Continent 
FROM w_Continent 
JOIN w_Country ON w_Continent.ID = w_Country.Continent 
GROUP BY w_Continent.ID
```

And here is the other relevant PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_GET['country'])) {
    $contQuery = "
    {$sqlQ}
    WHERE w_Continent.ID = ID
    ";

    $continent = $db->prepare($contQuery);

    $continent->execute(['ID' => $_GET['country']]);

    $selectedCont = $continent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($selectedCont);
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you var dumping?  whatever you are passing to var_dump() evaluates to false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row()/mysql\_num\_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc)

Comment: I am var dumping the returned value of the variable defined in the following line of code $selectedCont = $continent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Set up your PDO connection so that it will throw exceptions for query errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php This will really help you when you're trying to debug this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders are prefixed with a colon `:`. Your query needs to have `:ID` to be able to use it as a placeholder and bind.

The `:` tells PDO that it's a named placeholder and not some other valid part of the query like a column name.

Comment: {$sqlQ}
    WHERE w_Continent.ID:ID
    "; Like this?

Comment: `WHERE w_Continent.ID=:ID`

Comment: Also, if your initial query has that group by, it will fail again because the group by needs to go after the where clause.

Comment: It needs to be grouped by the ID to avoid duplication in my dropdown which is dynamically populated.

Comment: if (isset($_GET['country'])) {
            $contQuery = "
            {$sqlQ}
            WHERE w_Continent.ID:ID
            "; NEW CODE

Comment: I'm not saying you can't use group by, but that you need to add group by after the where clause.

Comment: Ahh I see, like so: if (isset($_GET['country'])) {
            $contQuery = "
            {$sqlQ}
            WHERE w_Continent.ID:ID
            GROUP BY w_Continent.ID
            ";

Comment: Yes. That. Or just append the group by afterwards regardless of if country is set.

Comment: Still no luck...tried using different variables incase I was referring to wrong one also, still not working!

Comment: You will have to look at your error log or turn on error reporting (and display errors) to see what the issue is then. Without that, you are just guessing blindly as to what the issue is. And this question is quickly getting too broad and a discussion which is not what SO is for.

Comment: Already showing errors using this:  ini_set('display_errors', true); //Display errors.
        error_reporting(-1); //show all errors.

Comment: And the error is? Did you set PDO to throw exceptions like suggested above?

Comment: Added some code to do as recommended, and following error showed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE w_Continent.ID:ID GROUP BY w_Continent.ID' at line 2'

Comment: You still need the `=` between the id and placeholder. `w_Continent.ID` is one value and `:ID` is the other. You are comparing them both with `=`.