# Why is this pdo fetch code not giving me what i want

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code for fetching data in pdo from my database:

```
<?php 
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `email` FROM hptenant WHERE user_id=:user_id');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['email'] . "\n";
} ?>
```

But anytime I use it, it will blank my page, that is nothing after this code will show (HTML). 
However if I use this one,

```
<?php $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT `email` FROM hptenant');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['email'] . "\n";
} ?>
```

It will show me the emails in my database. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: I don't see where you are passing `:user_id`. If you pass nothing to a query that is set to pull a row of data based on a variable, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to prepare, then either execute or bind/execute. You can't use bound parameters with `query`

Comment: It may be worth enabling some form of error reporting (if you haven't already) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php gives one solution.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't binding anything to `:user_id`

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `email` FROM hptenant WHERE user_id=:user_id');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $USER_ID_HERE);
$stmt->execute();
// while loop was unnecessary here (assuming user_id is unique)
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['email'] . "\n";
```

Comment: The `WHILE` loop is not necessary here, assuming no 2 users will have the same `user_id` (which they shouldn't).

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm sure but I didn't want to stray from the original code.

Comment: I don't think fixing an oversight would be straying from the original code, and it's probably better to show op the _correct_ way to do it. This loop adds unneeded overhead that the OP may not realize.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you're right, I've removed the unneeded loop

Comment: @John, Please let me ask this sort of 'silly' question, what is the difference between the user_I'd that I used and the suggested $USER_ID_HERE. Is it something I need to declare? I am new to PHP especially PDO so bear with my question.

Comment: You need to pass the desired user_id to bindParam so you can get the correct user from the database.