# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool

Tags: php, html, database, web, pdo

Hello i made a small searchengine with a webcrawler. I use PDO for the Database. But if i changed this line:

`` $web = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `sites`"); ``

in this line:

`` $web = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE title LIKES `$search`"); ``

I have this error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lens-Application\LensGO\results.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Lens-Application\LensGO\results.php(42): getWeb() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lens-Application\LensGO\results.php on line 28

And this is line 28: print_r($web->fetchAll());**

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Guess [`PDO::query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) returned false. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776344/how-to-view-query-error-in-pdo-php.

Comment: @Jeto but now it says this is wrong:
foreach($searche as $term)

Comment: PHP never says `this is wrong`. Provide the actual error message. Looks like you are using the wrong syntax and are open to SQL injections. Quotes are for strings, backticks for identifiers.

Comment: @user3783243 but i have now this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lens-Application\LensGO\results.php on line 27

Comment: So you likely didn't end the line above with a semicolon.

Comment: @user3783243 The complete line: foreach($searche as $term) { //CODE }

Comment: The error is from before that line. The `foreach` is "unexpected" so something is expected before it.

Comment: `LIKES` < why is that pluralized?

Comment: I don't know why this was hammered, it should be been closed as a typographical error, far as I'm concerned.